# IntelliJ cursor moving on autocompile

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ on OS X 10.9. The Java code keeps autocompiling after every input. Whenever it finds an error (which it often does, since it happens midway through the word) it moves the cursor somewhere else in the code. The only way of stopping it I found is using power save mode, which disables ANY code checking. Is there an option that serves as some kind of middle ground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | [ ] Automatically show first error in editor